# Coinbase Oauth2 application transaction send scope restrictions

Tags: coinbase-api

I am using Coinbase NPM package to send BTC payments from one account to another but my limit as listed by coinbase is: `wallet:transactions:send is limited $1.00/day per user`

This page - https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/coinbase-connect/permissions mentions that the limit can be raised in the Application Settings but I see no such setting. Had anyone run into this before?

Comment: We have the same issue and can't resolve it for more than 2 months already. Can you tell me, the account that you created the OAuth application, does it belong to a US citizen? We are from Armenia and we suspect that the limit might be because of the origin of our accounts